# Jenkins Groovy Parallel Variable not working

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing

I'm running the Jenkins Build Flow Plugin with the following script:

```
def builds = [:]

[1,2].each { 
  builds[it] = { build("test", parm: ("$it"))  }
}

parallel builds
```

However, whilst the hash (builds[it]) gets populated correctly, the parm is always null.  I've also tried the following:

```
builds[it] = { build("test", parm: $it))  }
builds[it] = { build("test", parm: it))  }
```

But the it is always null.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how I can use the $it, or any other variable in the build jobs please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are running into a bug in Build Flow Plugin (I've seen similar issues with Pipeline DSL). No expert, but it seems to be related to groovy closures and scoping of outer variables that are provided by `each` or `foreach` constructs.
For example (smilar to your example):

```
def builds = [:]

[1,2].each { 
  builds[a] = { print "${it}\n"  }
}

parallel builds
```

prints:

```
null
null
```

while:

```
def builds = [:]

[1,2].each { 
  def a = it;
  builds[a] = { print "${a}\n"  }
}

parallel builds
```

will print

```
1
2
```

as expected. So, use an local variable to store the iteration value.

Comment: awesome, didn't realise there was a bug, but your solution works great, thanks.

Comment: Maybe not a bug and it's seems to be general to groovy, found this blog post about the issue http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [build flow documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) I believe the syntax should be:

```
builds[it] = { build("test", param1: it) }
```

i.e. the `param1` argument name needs to literally read `param` followed by a sequential integer starting with 1.

Comment: I still get no parameter value passed to the job