# Simple parallel execution in Jenkins for an array

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm having trouble running a **Jenkins** job using Groovy, and it seems super simple but I'm 1) a noob at Java/Groovy and 2) all the examples I can find are not quite what I need to do.

I found the following similar question:
[Jenkins Groovy Parallel Variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039851/jenkins-groovy-parallel-variable-not-working), but that **exact** code results in an error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Calling public static
>   java.util.List
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(java.lang.Object,groovy.lang.Closure)
>   on a CPS-transformed closure is not yet supported (JENKINS-26481);
>   encapsulate in a @NonCPS method, or use Java-style loops

Here's my pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```
String[] arr = [ "one","two","three",'four','five' ]
echo "Running commands: ${arr}"
int top = arr.size()
echo "top is ${top}"
parallel arr.each {
    echo "${it}"
}
```

I've tried closures, but they throw an error and honestly I barely know how to use them.
The following code

```
String[] arr = [ "one","two","three",'four','five' ]
echo "Running commands: ${arr}"

parallel arr.collect { item ->
    { -> 
        echo "${item}"
    }
}
```

throws the same "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" as the related question above.

I'm trying to learn how to properly utilize Groovy with Jenkins, but it's been rough.  Just looking for any help I can get at this point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT:** In modern Jenkins (tested in 2.150.1) the original bug listed above is fixed, and `.each` works. You can do the following for parallel execution:

```
String[] arr = [ "one","two","three",'four','five' ]

def stepsForParallel = [:]
arr.each {
    def stepName = "running ${it}"
    stepsForParallel[stepName] = { ->           
        echo "${it}"
    }
}
parallel stepsForParallel
```

**ORIGINAL:**
It's a pretty annoying limitation, but currently you can't use `.each` in a pipeline script (as documented here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481)

You need to do an actual loop, like

```
String[] arr = [ "one","two","three",'four','five' ]
echo "Running commands: ${arr}"
int top = arr.size()
echo "top is ${top}"
for (it in arr) {
    echo "${it}"
}
```

If actually need parallel execution the code will look more like:

```
String[] arr = [ "one","two","three",'four','five' ]
echo "Running commands: ${arr}"
int top = arr.size()
echo "top is ${top}"
def stepsForParallel = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    def it = arr[i]
    def stepName = "running ${it}"
    stepsForParallel[stepName] = { ->           
        echo "${it}"
    }
}

parallel stepsForParallel
```

The other stackoverflow you linked to uses the Build Flow plugin, which is the predecessor to the Pipeline plugin that you're using. That's why the same code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, What's the need for closure here? Can't I just assign: `stepsForParallel[stepName] = echo "${it}"`?

Comment: I think this is for a scripted pipeline, as opposed to a declarative pipeline,  yes? If so, it might be worth pointing that out for people who are newer to Jenkins Pipeline workflows.

Comment: @AdilSadik correct, although it's simple to plug any Scripted syntax into a Declarative pipeline by either wrapping it in a `script { ... }` block or putting the script into a .groovy file and `load`ing it. (or put it in the `vars/` dir in a library and call it as a step, but that's more advanced.)